# input value not responding to "keyup" event

Tags: javascript

I am having problem with the following code. It is a simple To Do app with Javascript. Following a tutorial, followed to the t. My app isn't working the way it is supposed to. When I press the enter key the input value should be added to the list and it is not. I can't find any flaw in the code.

Also when I call the function manually `addToDo("read");` it shows up alright. But the enter button is not responding. Any advice will be appreciated.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === 13) {
        const toDo = input.value;
        if (toDo) {
            addToDo(toDo);
        } //end if toDo
    } // end if event.key

});
```

Comment: Can you show how `input` is defined? It is not given in the code

Comment: Where did you define the "input" variable?

Comment: `event.key==='Enter'` and event.target.value

Comment: I was going to post the "input" but all your answers already solved my problem. Thank you so much guys. Still learning. Hopefully in the future I will give back to the community. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're not checking for the proper `key` value on the `keyup` event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

You can check for the 'Enter' key on the `keyup` event like so:

```
txtTodo.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
});
```

A live example can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dbkf53w2/

Answer (score 2):

```js
function addToDo(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

document
  .querySelector('#input-field')
  .addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      const toDo = event.target.value;

      if (toDo) {
        addToDo(toDo);
      } //end if toDo
    } // end if event.key
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field">
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.key` value has a string value. Try with 'Enter' rather than 13. Number is keyCode. When trying to console `event.keyCode` then it shows numbers.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
console.log(event.keyCode);
if(event.key=== 'Enter'){
    //const toDo = input.value;
    //if(toDo){
      //  addToDo(toDo);
console.log('Enter')

    //}//end if toDo
}// end if event.key
})
```

```html
<div>Push 'Enter' please</div>
```

Comment: Do note that `keyCode` is a deprecated property:  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode